# Почему python выдаёт исключение при выполнении кода , полностью скопированного с документации по pytesseract?

Tags: python

Полностью проверенный и полностью скопированный код , который выдаёт ошибку , даже картинку использую , которая была на сайте[image: Используемое изображение]

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import cv2
import os

image = 'C:\bot\test2.png'


preprocess = "thresh"

# загрузить образ и преобразовать его в оттенки серого
image = cv2.imread(image)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# проверьте, следует ли применять пороговое значение для 
предварительной обработки изображения

if preprocess == "thresh":
    gray = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255,
        cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# если нужно медианное размытие, чтобы удалить шум
elif preprocess == "blur":
    gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 3)

# сохраним временную картинку в оттенках серого, чтобы 
можно было применить к ней OCR

filename = "{}.png".format(os.getpid())
cv2.imwrite(filename, gray)

# загрузка изображения в виде объекта image Pillow, 
применение OCR, а затем удаление временного файла
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename))
os.remove(filename)
print(text)

# показать выходные изображения
cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.imshow("Output", gray)
input('pause…')
```

Генерируемые исключения

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.3.0) C:\projects\opencv- 
python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: 
(-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 
'cv::cvtColor'
```

Comment: А попробуйте вывести картинку `image`: `cv2.imshow('ImageWindow', image); cv2.waitKey()`. Вообще, я вижу, что у вас путь к картинке может быть неправильно `cv2` распознан, смотрите за слешами, они у вас экранируют символы в пути, нужно так: `r'C:\bot\test2.png'` или так `'C:\\bot\\test2.png'`

Comment: И опять: используйте модуль `pathlib`

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, не, там другая причина -- не указана была камера

Comment: @dIm0n если нужно просто указать путь, то pathlib не нужен, достаточно r-строк.

Comment: @insolor не согласен, для кроссплатформенной разработки надо использовать специальные модули

Comment: @dIm0n, если нужна кроссплатформенность, достаточно указать путь с прямыми слешами - винда такое поймет. А модули path и pathlib нужно использовать когда нужно редактировать пути.

Comment: @insolor зачем думать, какая ОС поймёт, а какая нет? Об этом подумали разработчики стандартного модуля

Comment: @dIm0n, потому что нужно *думать*, и использовать подходящий инструмент в подходящем случае, а не тупо использовать одно и то же решение для всех случаев. В данном случае путь изначально платформозависимый, использование pathlib никакой кроссплатформенности не прибавит. Поэтому в данном случае достаточно указать путь как r-строку.

Comment: @insolor `pathlib` — подходящий инструмент для любых махинаций с путями; достаточное решение не обязательно является правильным

Comment: @dIm0n в том-то и дело, что тут нет никаких махинаций с путями, а нужно просто указать путь. И если использовать pathlib, то вместо простой строки `image = r'C:\bot\test2.png'` получим уродливое `Path('C:') / 'bot' / 'test2.png'`. Никакой выгоды - ни с точки зрения удобства, ни с точки зрения читаемости, ни с точки зрения кроссплатформенности (из-за того что путь изначально не платформозависимый). Ну и `достаточное решение не обязательно является правильным` верно и в обратную сторону, и ни разу не аргумент. Давайте на этом и закончим.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Причина ошибки в том, что путь к картинке был неправильный из-за слешей, что экранировали символы в пути.

Варианты:

1. Попробуйте использовать raw-строки, чтобы слеши в них не вызывали экранирование:

   ```
   image = r'C:\bot\test2.png'
   ```
2. Либо используйте обычные строки, но добавляя дополнительные слеши:

   ```
   image = 'C:\\bot\\test2.png'
   ```
3. Еще вариантом может быть использование других слешей:

   ```
   image = 'C:/bot/test2.png'
   ```
4. Если используете в проекте [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), то путь через него можно указать:

   Получите объект, представляющий путь:

   ```
   from pathlib import Path

   DIR = Path(r'C:\bot')
   file_name = DIR / 'test2.png'
   print(repr(file_name), file_name.exists())
   # WindowsPath('C:/bot/test2.png') True
   ```

   Стандартные библиотеки умеют работать с `Path` (например `open`, `glob`, ...), но сторонние могут не поддерживать (`opencv` например), поэтому можно получить путь как строку, используя `str()`:

   ```
   file_name = str(DIR / 'test2.png')
   print(file_name)
   # C:\bot\test2.png
   ```